# css halfstar colors

Tags: html, css

I've a question about star-symbols for rating showing. I have code

```
<style>
    .goldstardiv { color: gold; }
    .goldgraystardiv { color: khaki; }
    .graystardiv { color: gray; }
</style>
<div class="goldstardiv">&#x2605;</div>
<div class="goldgraystardiv">&#x2605;</div>
<div class="graystardiv">&#x2605;</div>
```

How to show with css a star having a gray left site and yellow right site?

Thank you

Comment: You are most likely going to have to do this with an image. You could of course use layered elements, but then you're just using unnecessary markup.

Comment: Are the stars really content?  This markup might be more appropriate: `<div class="3_half_stars">Three and a half out of 5 stars</div>` combined with a spritemap containing every possible combination of filled and half filled stars that you plan to use.  This would potentially make more sense to visually impaired users.

Comment: @cimmanon Decided to have a play with my answer based on your comment about stars not being content... Not that I think a spritemap is a bad solution but check it out, you can do the same thing with pure css.

Answer (score 4):

Put a div with a half grayed star (width 50% overflow hidden) over the colored one.

Html:

```
<div class="goldstardiv">
    &#x2605;
    <div class="halfstar">&#x2605;</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.goldstardiv { color: gold; position: relative; }
.halfstar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 8px;    
    color: #666;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

​
Half star with is given in pixels, but fiddle around with it to get it in % if you want.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LV7SS/2/

Comment: Who is the joker tossing around with - votes without explaining his reasoning ? Jed Watson got a - vote and so did this answer, while both provide an answer to the question. Tactical - voting?

Comment: Might be so, but semantically using stars without providing a numeric score (preferably rich snippets) is bad either way. In the given example adding a div which makes the solution cross browser seems pretty valid to me.

Comment: I agree that both the original source and your solution are semantically poor, hence my comment on the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this with pure CSS is with a nasty hack [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wdU3e/2/), which isn't really ideal. This uses a negative margin(`margin-left: -104px;`) to position the grey div over the gold one.

You would be better off using images and sprites

Comment: That isn't pure CSS then, is it? +1 for solving the problem though.

Comment: First solution was pure CSS (just margins, widths and overflow hidden). Recommended solution would be to use images (so not pure CSS)

Comment: No, you're overlaying a element with another element. This involves markup, so it isn't pure CSS. That is to say, you can't get a single star div to be colored half and half using your approach. You have to use another one.

Comment: Your fiddle looks crazy in Webkit - half star in the middle overlaps the first Gold one. Which browser does it work in?

Comment: @JedWatson Firefox looks OK.

Comment: Of course im using an element, but I didn't modify his markup, so I'd say its a pure CSS solution as all I did was change css. @JedWatson It work's fine in my chrome

Comment: @Andy right, maybe just Safari then... Also - I'd argue there is another way to do it in pure CSS, see my answer, doesn't modify the markup either. Still hacky :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the content:after property in CSS to display a second gold star over the gray one like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.star {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.star.gold { color: gold; }
.star.gold-gray { color: gray; }
.star.gold-gray:after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: gold;
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -16px;
    width: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.star.gray { color: gray; }​
</style>

<div class="star gold">&#x2605;</div>
<div class="star gold-gray">&#x2605;</div>
<div class="star gray">&#x2605;</div>​
```

You do need to be specific about sizes for this to work properly, so that you can correctly set the negative margin on the half-star, and crop it at half-width using overflow:hidden, but it does what you're after.

(I haven't specified font-size in the example, you may want to do that also)

Up-side to this technique is that you don't need additional markup in your html for the half-star, just the correct class.

**EDIT**

Somehow I pasted the wrong link to my jsFiddle, from a previous version I was still hacking the solution, rather than the working one... Probably deserved the downvote for that, but it **does** work!

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ah8uZ/).

**EDIT 2**

cimmanon mentioned the stars 'not really being content', which is quite true, but since the question asked for a CSS solution to the problem, I made one that doesn't require a sprite-map with all possible combinations.

Not because I've got anything against sprite maps - I don't - just because I wanted to have a go at it :)

Still including `<span>` elements for each star (hard to avoid) but aside from that it's all good markup and I assume would work pretty well for a screenreader.

[Check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4e8e/).

```
<style type="text/css">
.stars .label {
    width: 1px;
    color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.star {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.star:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '\2605';
}
.star.on { color: gold; }
.star.half { color: gray; }
.star.half:after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: gold;
    content: '\2605';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -16px;
    width: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.star.off { color: gray; }​
</style>

<div class="stars">
    <span class="label">One and a half start (out of three)</span>
    <span class="star on"></span>
    <span class="star half"></span>
    <span class="star off"></span>
</div>​
```

Comment: maibe you can provide this version that IE8-browsr can read it correctly.

Comment: On a mac unfortunately but there may be a way - I'll check it out tomorrow at work when I can get IE8 to test it on.